# Implementing Azure AD B2C Authentication in .NET 8 Blazor Project (RenderMode: InteractiveAuto)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on a .NET 8 Blazor project and I'm trying to implement Azure AD B2C authentication. According to Microsoft's documentation, I'm using `RemoteAuthenticatorView`. It works fine in WebAssembly mode, but I'm encountering issues when using "Interactive Auto".

When I use "Interactive Auto", I get the following error:

Cannot provide a value for property ‘AuthenticationService’ on type ‘Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticatorView’. There is no registered service of type ‘Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IRemoteAuthenticationService`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState]’

In an attempt to resolve this, I added `builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();` to my code. However, this resulted in another error:

Unable to cast object of type ‘Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider’ to type ‘Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IRemoteAuthenticationService`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState]’

I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve these errors and successfully implement Azure AD B2C authentication in my Blazor project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests there might be an issue with the AuthenticationStateProvider being used. Make sure you are using the correct provider for Blazor WebAssembly. It should be RemoteAuthenticationStateProvider.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RemoteAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```